# Error tras actualizar gradle 8.0, compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Ha salido versión nueva de android studio flamingo y con ello nuevo plugin de gradle, he pulsado actualizar versión a la 8.0 y ahora los proyectos arroja el siguiente error

`compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version. Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es el build.gradle a nivel de aplicación

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
```

y tener que especificar en settings del proyecto que se debe usar JDK 17, que ya viene preinstalado en android studio flamingo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]